# R Shiny Pass a vector as radioButtons choices argument

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to define a radio button in Shiny which normally I could do for example as:

```
radioButtons("choose_country", h3("Country"),
             choices=c('uganda'='UG','tanzania'='TZ','kenya'='KE'))
```

Which gives the desired output:

However, I would like the choices part of `radioButtons` to be read from an
externally defined vector. i.e.

```
country_assg <- c('uganda'='UG','tanzania'='TZ','kenya'='KE')
```

I would then like to paste this vector as follows:

```
radioButtons("choose_country", h3("Country"),
               choices=country_assg)
```

This does not seem to work as it seems not to break up the elements in the `country_assg` vector as required.

My question is how I can make `country_assg` to be evaluated as the choice argument inside the 
`radioButtons` command so that I get the desired output.
I would appreciate ideas to tackle the issue.

Comment: Hi amo! Do you have a skeletal server.R and ui.R to quickly reproduce your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, compiling the following three files does the job (all files in the same folder as always):

**ui.R:**

```
source('helpers.R')

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("censusVis"),

    radioButtons("choose_country", h3("Country"),
                 choices=c('uganda'='UG','tanzania'='TZ','kenya'='KE')),
    radioButtons("choose_country", h3("Country"),
                 choices=country_assg)

    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
source("helpers.R")

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {


    }
)
```

and **helpers.R**

```
country_assg <- c('uganda'='UG','tanzania'='TZ','kenya'='KE')
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Strictly speaking, you do not need to `source` the `helpers.R` in the server portion of this little app, because `server.R` does not require any of the definitions made in `helpers.R`.

Comment: I could also put that line from the helpers.R into the global.R which would not require sourcing in the ui.R